# VS 2022 Teams App - identify run environment in startup code?

Tags: microsoft-teams

VS 2022 Teams App: in startup code i.e. program.cs I need to identify if the app is running either in Teams or as a standalone web app. This is to properly configure authentication to suit the specific environment before app.Run(), as I need the app to be able to run as either Teams-hosted or standalone web.

Answer (score 0):

For Personal apps, in your manifest you are able to specify a `contentUrl`, which is the url that is rendered for your app when *inside* Microsoft Teams, as well as a `websiteUrl`, which is what will get shown when your app is opened outside of the Teams context (e.g. if the user clicks the button to load the web view, or I think some mobile devices render this by default). See more [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tabs/how-to/create-personal-tab?pivots=node-java-script#add-a-content-page-to-the-personal-tab).

For a Channel or Chat tab, you have a "Configuration" page that the user sees first - the small popup for configuring your tab, and likewise here you set a `contentUrl` and a `websiteUrl` (see more [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tabs/how-to/create-tab-pages/configuration-page?tabs=teamsjs-v2)).

In both these cases, you can actually set the -same- url, but with a different querystring value to indicate to your backend which view it is, and then use that value to do what you need.